# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on separate file

Tags: php

I am trying to add the begin of an if condition and the end of the if condition in separate file included into another file.

I have a file called cp.php which include header.php and footer.php and looks like this:

```
<?php 
require_once "includes/header.php";
?>
<p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
<p>
   This is an example protected page.  To access this page, users
   must be logged in.  At some stage, we'll also check the role of
   the user, so pages will be able to determine the type of user
   authorised to access the page.
</p>
<?php
  require_once "includes/sidebar.php";
  require_once "includes/footer.php";
?>
```

header.php

```
<?php
  include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
  include_once 'includes/functions.php';
  sec_session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  </body>
  <?php if (login_check($db) == true) : ?> // this if I am trying to end in footer.php
```

footer.php

```
  <?php else : ?>
  <?php header('index.php');
  <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in header.php on line 9` that would be the line with `<?php if (login_check($db) == true) : ?>`. Where am I mistaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead and remove it from HTML code:

`if (login_check($db) !== true) { header('Location: index.php'); exit; }`

Put the whole logic in the beginning

Comment: Tried this, and it's working only when I am logged in. If I am logged out it doesn't go to the else, to redirect me back to index.php.

Comment: There is no need for an else. This code means that if I am not logged in then redirect me to the index.php, anyways do nothing and continue running this script. (Assuming that login_check returns true on logged in, and fals if not)

Comment: In this case it works like this: even if I am logged out I still can view the protected content, instead of redirecting me to `index.php`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the copied code has been wrong. Edited the answer

Comment: Yes, working perfectly now, if I would have had rep bigger than 15, would have send 1 vote.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ":" in the top of line 9 in headers.php. Replace with empty brackets

```
<?php if (login_check($db) == true) {} ?>
```

Comment: Almost, now I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in footer.php on line 1`. How would I replace in this case with brackets?

Comment: remove <?php else : ?> <?php header('index.php');  <?php endif; ?> replace with `<?php else { require('index.php'); } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

PHP Parses files first then executes them, which means they each need to be complete and correct. Unfortunately you can't span if statements across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` clause cannot span over multiple files. You must either move the whole if-logic into one PHP file or add it to both files.

Answer (score 0):

The if-conditional structure should be:

```
if($a) {
    echo $a;
}
else:
    echo $c;
endif;
```

So you will have insert  an endif; at the end of the conditional.

This [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) will give you an idea.